# How can I make a shell script to grep over a set of log files counting how many lines match a keyword over dates?

Tags: linux, bash

I have a list of email logs, each about 1 GB in size:

```
logEmail                  logEmail-20200703.055047  logEmail-20200930.071224  logEmail-20210127.053615
logEmail-20200523.065336  logEmail-20200813.071542  logEmail-20201116.043541
```

In these files there are lines with dates and times, and some of the lines say that an email was queued to be sent. Those lines contain dates with this format:

```
28-Jan-21
```

and the keyword `queued` in the line.

For example, if I want to know how many emails were queued on 28-Jan-21 and I know all the email events for that date were in the file logEmail I could use this simple grep to count the results:

```
grep "28-Jan-21" logEmail | grep "queued" | wc
```

What I'd like to do in a script is get those counts for all the dates from the first date in the logs, 09-Apr-20 (April 20, 2020) through the last date in the logs, 03-Feb-2021 (February 3, 2021).

Is there a way I can write a shell script a loop to grep through all the logs over all the dates like that and generate a list of dates with wc results? It doesn't necessarily need to be wc - I'm just interested in the number of lines that match.

Every line in the log starts with the date. Here is a sample line that I'm looking for, with the email address hidden:

```
03-Feb-21 20:06:45 smtp-out OK ID=1035068 Send email.   Outgoing message queued To: xxx@xxxxx.org   From: message@xxx.xxx
```

Thanks.

Comment: @oguzismail There is example of log entries and good description about expected output.

Comment: @DougLerner : I would not use `grep` for this, because it means that if you consider n different dates and have m logfiles in total, you would create 2*n*m grep-processes. Instead I would write a single program, which holds an associative array where the keys are the dates, and then loop inside this program over all files and sum up the count of the 'queued' events per day simultaneously.

Comment: I suppose I could concatenate all the log files into one. It would still be a big file to search for each date though.

Comment: Does each line start with the date? A few lines example is appreciated.

Comment: I've added a sample line. Every line in the log, whether it's one I'm look for or not, starts with the date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you are only interested in lines that contain the word "queued", then `grep` for it:

```
grep -h -F -w queued logEmail*
```

In those lines, only the date matters, so drop the other fields:

```
grep -h -F -w queued logEmail* \
| cut -d " " -f1
```

Next, let's sort the dates:

```
grep -h -F -w queued logEmail* \
| cut -d " " -f1 \
| sort -t- -k3,3 -k2,2M -k1,1
```

Note: if instead of `logEmail*` we had specified `logEmail-* logEmail`, the dates would probably be already sorted, but anyway adding a `sort` won't hurt much (if this really takes too much additional time, you can avoid it).

Finally, let's count the number of times each date appears:

```
grep -h -F -w queued logEmail* \
| cut -d " " -f1 \
| sort -t- -k3,3 -k2,2M -k1,1 \
| uniq -c
```

Note: `uniq -c` counts the number of identical consecutive lines. That's why it is important that all the dates be sorted.

(update) If you want the date first and a CSV output, then let's ask `awk` to rearrange that output:

```
grep -h -F -w queued logEmail* \
| cut -d " " -f1 \
| sort -t- -k3,3 -k2,2M -k1,1 \
| uniq -c \
| awk '{ print $2 "," $1 }'
```

---

What follows is *not* the command you are looking for but, as a bonus, if you want to sort the result according to the number that now prefixes the dates:

```
grep -h -F -w queued logEmail* \
| cut -d " " -f1 \
| sort -t- -k3,3 -k2,2M -k1,1 \
| uniq -c \
| sort -n
```

Comment: Before testing this interesting looking answer I have a stupid question. What are the backslashes for? Does it just allow us to continue a long command on the next line? Thanks.

Comment: Exactly, else with long one-line commands, my answer would be barely readable. You can directly copy-paste a whole set of lines with the backslashes, bash will understand them.

Comment: Very very interesting! Thanks! I tested it on one small server, and then tried it on the main server and it works and is fast! One thing though - dates are not sorted. The results look like this (just showing the end portion):  
  
 101097 logEmail-20200703.055047:09-Jun-20  
 109405 logEmail-20200523.065336:28-Apr-20  
 118190 logEmail-20210127.053615:27-Jan-21  
 146092 logEmail-20201116.043541:07-Oct-20  
 153180 logEmail-20200523.065336:22-Apr-20  
 159807 logEmail-20201116.043541:09-Oct-20  
 261648 logEmail-20210127.053615:21-Jan-21  
 554001 logEmail-20201116.043541:29-Oct-20

Comment: Hoooo, my bad, I forgot there were multiple files. This should be a `grep -h`. Updating my answer.

Comment: The output looks much cleaner now without the filenames. Is that what -h does, hide the filename? Nice to know.  It still isn't sorted though. Here's a portion:  138709 23-May-20
 146092 07-Oct-20
 153180 22-Apr-20
 156504 27-Jan-21
 159807 09-Oct-20
 261648 21-Jan-21
 554001 29-Oct-20

Comment: It might just be very difficult to sort by dates because of the particular date format. I can obviously sort the results in an editor or Excel. So thank you again!

Comment: Well, if you ran the last command, this is normal: as a bonus, I gave you a way to sort the lines by the first number (the count) instead of the dates. `sort` has no problem sorting this date format. What you are looking for is the second to last command.

Comment: Indeed that is what I am looking for. It is perfect. And fast. I appreciate it. I will study those commands to try to figure out how you did that! I think I see most of it. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm pushing my luck here, but thought I would ask: why do the dates follow the numbers? Is there a way of outputting so it's date and then count?

Comment: This is the output of `uniq`. We can rearrange that with `awk` (updating my answer again). Do you want a CSV output too?

Comment: That's what the new "," part does, right? It's perfect. I learned quite a lot today and greatly appreciate it. Thanks for your guidance.

Comment: Yes, for each line, we ask `awk` to print the second field (`$2`), then a comma, then the first field (`$1`)